# Terminal doesn't end process after using rails g model command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

I recently find sometimes when I use rails command in terminal, it won't end the process itself:

```
blog (master) $ rails g model Article title:string text:text
Running via Spring preloader in process 33892
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20161029085205_create_articles.rb
      create    app/models/article.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/article_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/articles.yml
```

and I have to manually close it with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>:

```
blog (master) $ rails g model Article title:string text:text
Running via Spring preloader in process 33892
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20161029085205_create_articles.rb
      create    app/models/article.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/article_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/articles.yml
^Cblog (master) $
```

It was fine before I updated MacOS to Sierra, but I'm not sure if that's the cause.

I followed all the step from [http://railsapps.github.io/](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) to install rvm, rails, etc. All I did additionally was to change my bash_profile to this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
source /Users/xiaohuli/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Does anyone have the same problem like mine? Why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The SO markdown parser uses a four space indent for code blocks (it sucks, we know). You can can select the code you want to indent and press the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: Got it! Thanks man, it looks much better!